# Can someone please tell me why this code is able to print the grouped data frame?

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

I used groupby operation on a df named reviews and wanted to display it.

```
reviews.groupby('taster_twitter_handle').apply(lambda x: x[:])
```

This works ^

```
reviews.groupby('taster_twitter_handle').apply(lambda x: x)
```

This does not ^

I am trying to get the grouped dataframe printed. The second option only prints the existing dataframe without any grouping.

Comment: what about the second option doesn't work? what are you trying to do?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. "This does not work" is not an adequate description of the problem, and we need enough code to be able to see the problem for ourselves. Also, keep in mind that this is *not a discussion forum*. We *do not care* about your background as a programmer, your opinion of the question, or greetings/sign-offs; we care about *the question*.

Comment: Hi. Sorry I need to make my question clearer. I am trying to get the combined dataframe displayed. When I use the second option it just displays the original dataframe and not thr combined one. The combined one is displayed with the first option. Hope that makes it more clear 

Comment: I'm wondering what you think this is doing. `.apply(lambda x: x)` does nothing.  For each row, it returns the row.  It replaces x with x.  Doesn't this work if you skip the `apply` completely?

Comment: Notice that .apply is being called on a GroupBy object. This means that the lambda gets called with each group as a dataframe. If it just returns the dataframes unchanged, they get re-assembled by apply() to something that resembles the original, un-grouped, dataframe. Apparently, the slicing does something to change how apply() re-assembles the values, but I'm not sure what, so this is a comment, not an answer...

Comment: This behaviour has been reported as [bug 14927](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/14927) on the Pandas Github repo.